# Calculating a contour integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

**Question**

Evaluate $$\int_S ze^{z^2}\,dz \\$$

Where S is the curve: $\gamma(t):= \sqrt{2}t+(1-t)i$ where $t \in [0,1]$

**My attempt:**

The question is worth very few marks so I know there must be a use of a theorem. I believe I should be using Cauchy-Goursat theorem but I am not sure how to use it in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(z)=\frac{1}{2}e^{z^2}$. Since
$$
f'(z)=ze^{z^2},
$$
$$
\int_S ze^{z^2} dz = f(\gamma(1))-f(\gamma(0))
$$
by [the fundamental theorem of calculus to contour integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus). It says:

> $^1$ Suppose that the function $f(z)$ is continuous in a domain $D$ and has an antiderivative $F(z)$ throughout $D$; i.e., $dF(z)/dz=f(z)$ for each $z$ in $D$. Then for any contour $\Gamma$ lying in $D$, with initial point $z_I$ and terminal point $z_T$, we have$$\int_\Gamma f(z) dz=F(z_T)-F(z_I).$$

Can you proceed?

---

$^1$ E. B. Saff, A. D. Snider (2003). *Fundamentals of Complex Analysis*. 3rd ed. Prentice Hall. page 173.

Comment: No, sorry I don't understand the thought process

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, I can proceed however it was more the initial step that I don't understand, why can you just pick a function and how does it relate to the integral?

Comment: @THISISIT453 Picking $f(z)$ and differentiating it is showing that $ze^{z^2}$ has an antiderivative, so that we can use the theorem. In general, $\frac{1}{2}e^{z^2}+c$ is an antiderivative of $ze^{z^2}$, where $c$ is any constant.

Comment: I see! Thank you very much!